# How to barplot time on the x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to create a bar plot where the x-axis is the `datetime` column from my data-frame.

I converted the `datetime` in `pandas` column to time only and I am getting an error when I try to use the `matplotlib.pyplot.barplot` function to plot the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataset['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['date']).dt.time

plt.bar(dataset['date'], dataset['tickqty'])
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'float'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-7ddd22154cf4>", line 7, in <module>
plt.bar(dataset['date'], dataset['tickqty'])

  File "/home/mahmoud/anaconda3/envs/fxenv/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2472, in bar
**({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

  File "/home/mahmoud/anaconda3/envs/fxenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1431, in inner
return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "/home/mahmoud/anaconda3/envs/fxenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2464, in bar
f'are incompatible') from e

 TypeError: the dtypes of parameters x (object) and width (float64) are incompatible
```

This is the data from the csv file:
[image]

How can I plot the time column in `matplotlib.pyplot.barplot`?

Comment: Question is: What was the intention for `pd.to_datetime(dataset['date']).dt.time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution with matplotlib bar plot

`pd.to_datetime(dataset['date']).dt.time` converts the dates to strings (dtype `object`) which is causing the `TypeError`. For `plt.bar` to work, you need to use numerical data. You can use the full dates stored as pandas `Timestamp` objects that you get when using `pd.to_datetime(dataset['date'])` and matplotlib will automatically process them as [matplotlib date units](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-date-format) (number of days since 1970-01-01 UTC).

Then you need to format the x-axis tick labels so that only the times are shown. This can be done by using the matplotlib.dates [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) with the appropriate [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). Here is an example using the data you shared in the image:

```
import pandas as pd                # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataset['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['date'])
plt.bar(dataset['date'], dataset['tickqty'], width=0.002)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.show()
```

[image: bar_plot_time_ticklabels]

Note that the bar `width` argument is using the x variable unit (i.e. matplotlib date units) which is time in days. So `0.002` corresponds to about 2 minutes and 53 seconds.