# bar plot with HH:MM:SS in x-axis

Tags: python, csv, plot, time, bar-chart

I have the following string in Python (got many of those):

```
date = "00:01:43"
```

which represents the hour::minute::seconds. This comes from reading a csv file which contains many of those date.

Now I need to construct those I am reading from csv to some sort of array and then use it for a bar plot (matloblib.bar) as the x-axis

The question is how do I prepare the dates I am reading to be used in a bar plot:

```
with open('file.csv','r')
    for line in file:
        time = line.split(',')[0] ## this is read like "HH:MM:SS"
        temp = line.split(',')[1] ## this is read like "Float as a string"
        tempArray.append(float(temp))
```

**QUESTION**

How do I assembly the time into an array to then be used in the following:
plt.bar(timeArray, tempArray)

where the x-axis would still show "HH:MM:SS" format.

Comment: I don't see a question here. What have you done so far?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I would convert all the values to a number of seconds (just an integer), then use [tick formatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) to get a custom printing of seconds as a human readable hour::minute::seconds format

Comment: Could you show it please

Comment: What is the specific problem here? As it stands, the question reads more like you're asking for a tutorial, such as [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_bar_plot.htm) or [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bar-plot-in-matplotlib/).

Comment: Is my question clear now _ ?

Comment: like this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386150/10197418 (they're using pandas, you don't have to do that, you can use native Python datetime instead)

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you have create a list for temp data, then you can just create another list for time data.
Then use ax.set_xticks({temp_data_list}, {time_data_list}) to group them together.

```
ax.set_xticks({temp_data_list}, {time_data_list})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).