# incompatible datatypes when plotting a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, statsmodels

I'm using ARIMA to predict the amount (Amt) for next 5 days of a dataset. The bar chart needs to show a concatenation of the amounts for each time value, and then the future prediction.

An example of the dataframe, its much larger than this:

```
  CCY Pair        Time   Amt
0   GBPUSD  13/05/2023  1000
1   EURUSD  13/05/2023  2000
2   EURUSD  14/05/2023  3000
3   EURUSD  14/05/2023  5000
4   GBPEUR  15/05/2023  4000
```

The code below gives me the following error when I try and plot the model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Graphs.py", line 46, in <module>
    plt.bar(combined_data.index, combined_data['Amt'])
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2439, in bar
    return gca().bar(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1442, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2460, in bar
    raise TypeError(f'the dtypes of parameters x ({x.dtype}) '
TypeError: the dtypes of parameters x (object) and width (float64) are incompatible
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA


# The "Time" column contains the time periods, and "Amt" contains the values
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

# Convert the "Time" column to a datetime type
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], dayfirst=True)

# Set the "Time" column as the index
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

# Sort the DataFrame by the index
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_period('D')

# Prepare the data for ARIMA modeling
data = df['Amt']

# Fit the ARIMA model
model = ARIMA(data, order=(1,0,0)) 
model_fit = model.fit()

# Predict the next x periods
x = 5  # Number of periods to predict
predictions = model_fit.forecast(steps=x)

# Generate the next x bar charts based on the predictions
next_time_periods = pd.date_range(start=df.index.max().to_timestamp() + pd.DateOffset(days=1), periods=x, freq='D')  # Generate x future time periods
next_bar_charts = pd.DataFrame({'Time': next_time_periods, 'Amt': predictions}, index=next_time_periods)

# Concatenate current and predicted bar chart data
combined_data = pd.concat([df, next_bar_charts])

# Plot the combined bar chart
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.bar(combined_data.index, combined_data['Amt'])
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Amt')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to barplot time on the x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383094/how-to-barplot-time-on-the-x-axis)

Comment: You have to make sure that the index of your resulting DataFrame `combined_data ` is a valid datetime object and not a string. The code for the bar plot is working, if the types are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `combined_data` index, you will notice that this is of type `Object` . This is because `next_bar_charts` index is not of the same type as `df` index. The x-axis for barplot needs to be in datetime format. So, the change you need to do are:

1. Comment out the line `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_period('D')`
2. Remove the `.to_timestamp()` while creating `next_time_periods` as this is no longer needed because of change #1
3. Once `combined_data` is created, add this line: `combined_data.index=pd.to_datetime(combined_data.index)` to convert the index to the datetime type

This should resolve your issue. Output with some random data is as below...

[image]